# How does craigslist get location

Tags: php, javascript, location, craigslist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [free geolocation geoip, are they viable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497965/free-geolocation-geoip-are-they-viable)

I would like to find the most precise method of tracking a visitor's location.  I noticed that craigslist can accurately get the user's location without requiring any input from the user.  Can anyone tell me what they are doing in order to track the user?  I'd like my web programs to be just as accurate as theirs.

note:  (I've been using JavaScript / PHP. )

Comment: geoiplookup, have free and commercial databases

Comment: When requests are sent they contain the IP address of the client in the header, and that can be used to determine your location at the city level. This is probably what Craigslist uses.

Answer (score 0):

They are almost certainly using a GeoIP database or web service of some kind. The most well known company offering these services is probably [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolocation_landing).

MaxMind offered free and less accurate version of their database last time I checked, and there are other providers offering free databases as well (none of which I can personally vouch for). There is a [discussion about these free alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2497965/free-geolocation-geoip-are-they-viable).

PHP has [a module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) which can be used with a GeoIP database like those supplied by MaxMind.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you would like to use this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Comment: Or simply use [HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)